# Derivation of option pricing PIDE: Why does the drift need to be zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, martingale, sde

I started studying PIDE methods for option pricing and am struggling to understand or find the necessary theory that shows why the PIDE is obtained by the condition that the drift term has to be zero.

I read this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24055746_Integro-Differential_Equations_for_Option_Prices_in_Exponential_Levy_Models) where asset models of the form $S_t = s_0 e^{rt + X_t}$ are considered, with $X$ being a Levy process with generating triplet $(\sigma^2,\gamma,\nu)$ and jump measure $J_X$. If $C(t,S_t)$ is the price function of a European option, one can apply Ito's formula to $\hat{C}_t=e^{r(T-t)}C(t,S_t)$ to obtain dynamics of the form
$$
d\hat{C}_t = a(t)dt  + dM_t
$$
where $M_t$ is a martingale consisting of a $dW_t$ and a $\tilde{J_X}(dt\ dx)$ part. As the discounted price process $\hat{C}_t$ is a martingale (by arbitrage theory), $\hat{C}_t - M_t$ is also a martingale. Up to here, everything is clear to me.

But then, the last part is, concluding that $a(t)$ has to be zero since $\hat{C}_t - M_t = \int_0^t a(s)ds$ is also continuous process with finite variation, justified with a reference to almost a whole section of this [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540439325), where I don't really see the connection to this reasoning.

So my questions are:

1. Why is $\hat{C}_t - M_t = \int_0^t a(s)ds$ a continuous process with finite variation? The process is given by
   $$
   a(t) = e^{r(T-t)} \left[ -rC(t,S_{t-}) + \partial_1 C(t,S_{t-}) + \frac{\sigma^2 S_{t-}^2}{2}\partial_2^2C(t,S_{t-}) + rS_{t-}\partial_2C(t,S_{t-}  \\
   + \int_\mathbb{R} C(t,S_{t-}e^x) - C(t,S_{t-}) - S_{t-}(e^x-1)\partial_2 C(t,S_{t-})\nu(dx) \right]
   $$
   I don't see immediately that the integral over this should be continuous and of finite variation.
2. Now given that this is true, why  is a martingale that is continuous and of finite variation equal to zero?

I would be happy for any kind of resources that give a clearer proof of this result than just referencing to a whole range of theorems and propositions in a book